# How can I have FogBugz show me cases with no recent activity?

Tags: fogbugz

I have a particular saved filter that shows me all cases in a specific project and area that are active and assigned to humans (by excluding some users that don't correspond to real people but are instead used for unrelated project management operations.

It looks something like:

```
"All open cases in PROJECT that are active containing -assignedto:"Non-Human User 1" -assignedto:"Non-Human User 2"
```

I would like to amend this filter to show me the subset of these cases that have had no edits of any kind in the last two weeks. I have tried adding various flavors of the `edited` axis using relative time ranges as I've seen examples of in the FogBugz documentation, but I get unexpected results every time. In particular, `-edited:"-2w.."` or even the simpler `-edited:"yesterday"` shows me results where the Last Updated column says, maddeningly, "DD/MM/YYYY (Yesterday)."

(This is with FB 8, for what it's worth).

Comment: Please email us directly at customer-service@fogcreek.com to talk about this. Or re-ask this question at fogbugz.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work reasonably close to what I expected by adding a search axis term for `edited:"..-2w"` (where -2w means "two weeks ago" and could of course be changed to whatever window of time was relevant). What tripped me up is that I was trying to *exclude* things edited between two weeks ago and now using `-edited` and that didn't quite do what I expected.

Instead, my final query looks like it is grabbing things edited from the dawn of time until two weeks ago (further restricted by additional filters of course).